# Laravel 4: how can I put data into every view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have an app that needs to get the menu from the database for each view / request. How should I do that? I want to put data into every view.

I see that there are [`View Composers`](http://four.laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers), but I can't just do `View::composer('*', ...)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a default view, you could use the view composer on that view to pass the menu.  It might look like this:

```
    View::composer('layout', function($view)
    {
        $view->with($menu,Menu::get());
    });
```

This will ensure that anytime your `layout` view is called, `$menu` will contain whatever is returned by your model.

Also, Laravel has `View::share('foo',$bar)` which will make `$foo` accessible in all your views and set it equal to $bar.  So if you do not have a single view, you may be able to make use of this to ensure you always have a `$menu` accessible.

Depending on your situation one might be better than the other

Comment: Great, thanks! Just please update your answer with my paste (http://paste.laravel.com/iM8), as this is the way to do it in Laravel 4.

Comment: And for others reading this, I did this using Blade Layouts (http://four.laravel.com/docs/templates), so I have a master template (master.blade.php) and then every other (basic / page) template extends this master template. So using a layout composer I was able to put data to this master template and thus to every page.